# How to make Button print the last updated point?

Tags: dynamic, curated-data, button

I am trying to create a graphics that outputs the population of a city on the graphics that is clicked. The problem is that it is not updating the last point that is clicked. Please help.

```
Button[Graphics[{Gray, CountryData["Australia", "Polygon"],
   PointSize[Large], Red,
   Tooltip[Point[Reverse[
        CityData[#, "Coordinates"]]], me = CityData[#, "Name"]] & /@ 
    CityData[{Large, "Australia"}]}], 
 Print[CityData[me, "Population"]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the assigment `me = CityData[#, "Name"]` in `Dynamic`, so that instead of being evaluated only when the button is created, it is evaluated each time the `Tooltip` is activated:

```
Button[Graphics[{Gray, CountryData["Australia", "Polygon"], 
   PointSize[Large], Red, 
   Tooltip[Point[Reverse[CityData[#, "Coordinates"]]], 
      Dynamic[me = CityData[#, "Name"]]] & /@ 
    CityData[{Large, "Australia"}]}], 
 Print[CityData[me, "Population"]]]
```